# Long loading time (dash table without all dropdowns fields display)

Tags: python, plotly-dash, plotly-python

It take a long time to load my dash table and not all the dropdowns are available.

Messages on the execution :

```
 * Serving Flask app "table_ARPEGE" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Apr/2021 21:54:24] "←[37mGET / HTTP/1.1←[0m" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Apr/2021 21:54:26] "←[37mGET /_dash-dependencies HTTP/1.1←[0m" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Apr/2021 21:54:26] "←[37mGET /_dash-layout HTTP/1.1←[0m" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Apr/2021 21:54:26] "←[37mGET /_dash-component-suites/dash_table/async-highlight.js HTTP/1.1←[0m" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Apr/2021 21:54:26] "←[37mGET /_dash-component-suites/dash_table/async-table.js HTTP/1.1←[0m" 200 -
```

Here are my settings for my dash table (size 35columns x 202rows) :

```
columns=[{'name': 'index', 'id': 'index', 'presentation': 'dropdown'}, 
{'name': 'UP', 'id': 'UP', 'presentation': 'dropdown'}, 
{'name': 'GEH', 'id': 'GEH'}, {'name': 'GU', 'id': 'GU'}, 
{'name': 'COD_NAT', 'id': 'COD_NAT', 'presentation': 'dropdown'}, 
{'name': 'USINE', 'id': 'USINE'}, 
{'name': 'GROUPES_DE_PRODUCTION', 'id': 'GROUPES_DE_PRODUCTION', 'presentation': 'dropdown'}, 
{'name': 'OBJECTIF_ANNEE_LIVRAISON', 'id': 'OBJECTIF_ANNEE_LIVRAISON'}, 
{'name': 'RESPONSABLE_GEH', 'id': 'RESPONSABLE_GEH'}, 
{'name': 'RESPONSABLE_RTE', 'id': 'RESPONSABLE_RTE'}, 
{'name': 'DCP_GEN', 'id': 'DCP_GEN'}, 
{'name': 'DCP_SPE', 'id': 'DCP_SPE'}, 
{'name': 'DONNEE_CIST', 'id': 'DONNEE_CIST', 'presentation': 'dropdown'}, 
{'name': 'JUSTIFICATIF_PMAX', 'id': 'JUSTIFICATIF_PMAX', 'presentation': 'dropdown'}, 
{'name': 'DOC_PERF_HTB', 'id': 'DOC_PERF_HTB', 'presentation': 'dropdown'}, 
{'name': 'DTG', 'id': 'DTG', 'presentation': 'dropdown'}, 
{'name': 'DATE_DTG', 'id': 'DATE_DTG'}, 
{'name': 'DTG_ALT_EXCIT_RGU_PA_TR', 'id': 'DTG_ALT_EXCIT_RGU_PA_TR', 'presentation': 'dropdown'},
 {'name': 'DATE_DTG_ALT_EXCIT_RGU_PA_TR', 'id': 'DATE_DTG_ALT_EXCIT_RGU_PA_TR'}, 
{'name': 'DTG_RGN', 'id': 'DTG_RGN', 'presentation': 'dropdown'},
 {'name': 'DATE_DTG_RGN', 'id': 'DATE_DTG_RGN'},
 {'name': 'DTG_PQ_PA', 'id': 'DTG_PQ_PA', 'presentation': 'dropdown'},
 {'name': 'DATE_DTG_PQ_PA', 'id': 'DATE_DTG_PQ_PA'},
 {'name': 'ESSAIS_RGU_EXCIT', 'id': 'ESSAIS_RGU_EXCIT', 'presentation': 'dropdown'}, {'name': 'DATE_ESSAIS_RGU_EXCIT', 'id': 'DATE_ESSAIS_RGU_EXCIT'},
 {'name': 'ESSAIS_RGN', 'id': 'ESSAIS_RGN', 'presentation': 'dropdown'},
 {'name': 'DATE_ESSAIS_RGN', 'id': 'DATE_ESSAIS_RGN'}, {'name': 'MODELISATION_RGU_EXCIT', 'id': 'MODELISATION_RGU_EXCIT'},
 {'name': 'DATE_MODELISATION_RGU_EXCIT', 'id': 'DATE_MODELISATION_RGU_EXCIT'},
 {'name': 'MODELISATION_RGN', 'id': 'MODELISATION_RGN', 'presentation': 'dropdown'},
 {'name': 'DATE_MODELISATION_RGN', 'id': 'DATE_MODELISATION_RGN'}, {'name': 'MODELISATION_CIST', 'id': 'MODELISATION_CIST', 'presentation': 'dropdown'},
 {'name': 'DATE_MODELISATION_CIST', 'id': 'DATE_MODELISATION_CIST'},
 {'name': 'TYPE_CONTRACTUALISATION', 'id': 'TYPE_CONTRACTUALISATION', 'presentation': 'dropdown'},
 {'name': 'DONNEE_SIMPLIFIE', 'id': 'DONNEE_SIMPLIFIE', 'presentation': 'dropdown'}]

dropdown={'DONNEE_CIST': {'options': [{'label': 'non', 'value': 'non'}, {'label': 'demandée', 'value': 'demandée'}, {'label': 'oui', 'value': 'oui'}]}, 
'JUSTIFICATIF_PMAX': {'options': [{'label': 'non', 'value': 'non'}, {'label': 'rédigé_a_valider', 'value': 'rédigé_a_valider'}, {'label': 'oui', 'value': 'oui'}]}, 
'DOC_PERF_HTB': {'options': [{'label': 'non_demarré', 'value': 'non_demarré'}, {'label': 'doc_de_relevé_demandé_cist', 'value': 'doc_de_relevé_demandé_cist'}, {'label': 'relevé_en_cours', 'value': 'relevé_en_cours'}, {'label': 'doc_perf_htb_demandé_cist', 'value': 'doc_perf_htb_demandé_cist'}, {'label': 'relevé_a_reprendre_up', 'value': 'relevé_a_reprendre_up'}, {'label': 'oui', 'value': 'oui'}]}, 
'DTG': {'options': [{'label': 's.o.', 'value': 's.o.'}, {'label': 'non_demarré', 'value': 'non_demarré'}, {'label': 'partiellement_renseigné', 'value': 'partiellement_renseigné'}, {'label': 'renseignées', 'value': 'renseignées'}, {'label': 'partiellement_validé', 'value': 'partiellement_validé'}, {'label': 'validées', 'value': 'validées'}, {'label': 'modeles_essais_données_oui', 'value': 'modeles_essais_données_oui'}]}, 
'DTG_ALT_EXCIT_RGU_PA_TR': {'options': [{'label': 's.o.', 'value': 's.o.'}, {'label': 'non_demarré', 'value': 'non_demarré'}, {'label': 'demarré_relancé', 'value': 'demarré_relancé'}, {'label': 'renseigné', 'value': 'renseigné'}, {'label': 'validation_relancée', 'value': 'validation_relancée'}, {'label': 'validé', 'value': 'validé'}, {'label': 'oui', 'value': 'oui'}]}, 
'DTG_RGN': {'options': [{'label': 's.o.', 'value': 's.o.'}, {'label': 'non_demarré', 'value': 'non_demarré'}, {'label': 'demarré_relancé', 'value': 'demarré_relancé'}, {'label': 'renseigné', 'value': 'renseigné'}, {'label': 'validation_relancée', 'value': 'validation_relancée'}, {'label': 'validé', 'value': 'validé'}, {'label': 'oui', 'value': 'oui'}]}, 
'DTG_PQ_PA': {'options': [{'label': 's.o.', 'value': 's.o.'}, {'label': 'non_demarré', 'value': 'non_demarré'}, {'label': 'demarré_relancé', 'value': 'demarré_relancé'}, {'label': 'renseigné', 'value': 'renseigné'}, {'label': 'validation_relancée', 'value': 'validation_relancée'}, {'label': 'validé', 'value': 'validé'}, {'label': 'oui', 'value': 'oui'}]}, 
'ESSAIS_RGU_EXCIT': {'options': [{'label': 's.o.', 'value': 's.o.'}, {'label': 'non_demarré', 'value': 'non_demarré'}, {'label': 'demarré', 'value': 'demarré'}, {'label': 'relancé', 'value': 'relancé'}, {'label': 'oui', 'value': 'oui'}]}, 
'ESSAIS_RGN': {'options': [{'label': 's.o.', 'value': 's.o.'}, {'label': 'non_demarré', 'value': 'non_demarré'}, {'label': 'demarré', 'value': 'demarré'}, {'label': 'relancé', 'value': 'relancé'}, {'label': 'oui', 'value': 'oui'}]}, 
'MODELISATION_RGN': {'options': [{'label': 's.o.', 'value': 's.o.'}, {'label': 'non_demarré', 'value': 'non_demarré'}, {'label': 'demarré', 'value': 'demarré'}, {'label': 'relancé', 'value': 'relancé'}, {'label': 'oui', 'value': 'oui'}]}, 
'MODELISATION_CIST': {'options': [{'label': 's.o.', 'value': 's.o.'}, {'label': 'non_demarré', 'value': 'non_demarré'}, {'label': 'demandé', 'value': 'demandé'}, {'label': 'relancé', 'value': 'relancé'}, {'label': 'oui', 'value': 'oui'}]}, 
'TYPE_CONTRACTUALISATION': {'options': [{'label': 'RF', 'value': 'RF'}, {'label': 'RU', 'value': 'RU'}, {'label': 'RF & RU', 'value': 'RF & RU'}, {'label': 's.o.', 'value': 's.o.'}]}, 'DONNEE_SIMPLIFIE': {'options': [{'label': 'oui', 'value': 'oui'}, {'label': 'non', 'value': 'non'}]}, 'UP': {'options': [{'label': 'Alpes', 'value': 'Alpes'}, {'label': 'Centre', 'value': 'Centre'}, {'label': 'Sud Ouest', 'value': 'Sud Ouest'}]}, 
'GROUPES_DE_PRODUCTION': {'options': [{'label': 'G2', 'value': 'G2'}, {'label': 'G1', 'value': 'G1'}, {'label': 'G3', 'value': 'G3'}, {'label': 'G4', 'value': 'G4'}, {'label': 'G5', 'value': 'G5'}, {'label': 'G6', 'value': 'G6'}, {'label': 'G7', 'value': 'G7'}, {'label': 'G8', 'value': 'G8'}, {'label': 'G9', 'value': 'G9'}, {'label': 'G10', 'value': 'G10'}, {'label': 'G11', 'value': 'G11'}, {'label': 'G12', 'value': 'G12'}, {'label': 'G13', 'value': 'G13'}, {'label': 'G14', 'value': 'G14'}, {'label': 'G15', 'value': 'G15'}, {'label': 'G16', 'value': 'G16'}, {'label': 'G17', 'value': 'G17'}, {'label': 'G18', 'value': 'G18'}, {'label': 'G19', 'value': 'G19'}, {'label': 'G20', 'value': 'G20'}, {'label': 'G21', 'value': 'G21'}, {'label': 'G22', 'value': 'G22'}, {'label': 'G23', 'value': 'G23'}, {'label': 'G24', 'value': 'G24'}, {'label': 'G25', 'value': 'G25'}, {'label': 'G26', 'value': 'G26'}, {'label': 'G27', 'value': 'G27'}, {'label': 'G28', 'value': 'G28'}, {'label': 'G29', 'value': 'G29'}, {'label': 'G30', 'value': 'G30'}]},
 'COD_NAT': {'options': [{'label': 'AIGLEH', 'value': 'AIGLEH'}, {'label': 'A.NORH', 'value': 'A.NORH'}, {'label': 'ARGE5H', 'value': 'ARGE5H'}, {'label': 'AUZERH', 'value': 'AUZERH'}, {'label': 'BEYSSH', 'value': 'BEYSSH'}, {'label': 'BORT H', 'value': 'BORT H'}, {'label': 'BROMMH', 'value': 'BROMMH'}, {'label': 'BRUGAH', 'value': 'BRUGAH'}, {'label': 'CAJARH', 'value': 'CAJARH'}, {'label': 'CAMBEH', 'value': 'CAMBEH'}, {'label': 'CSLNAH', 'value': 'CSLNAH'}, {'label': 'CHARDH', 'value': 'CHARDH'}, {'label': 'CHASTH', 'value': 'CHASTH'}, {'label': 'CHATRH', 'value': 'CHATRH'}, {'label': 'CTLUSH', 'value': 'CTLUSH'}, {'label': 'COUESH', 'value': 'COUESH'}, {'label': 'EGUZOH', 'value': 'EGUZOH'}, {'label': 'ENCHAH', 'value': 'ENCHAH'}, {'label': 'FADE5H', 'value': 'FADE5H'}, {'label': 'GOLINH', 'value': 'GOLINH'}, {'label': 'GRAN6H', 'value': 'GRAN6H'}, {'label': 'GRANDH', 'value': 'GRANDH'}, {'label': 'GUERLH', 'value': 'GUERLH'}, {'label': 'HAUTEH', 'value': 'HAUTEH'}, {'label': 'JOUSSH', 'value': 'JOUSSH'}, {'label': 'LAFIGH', 'value': 'LAFIGH'}, {'label': 'LAMATH', 'value': 'LAMATH'}, {'label': 'LANAUH', 'value': 'LANAUH'}, {'label': 'LARDIH', 'value': 'LARDIH'}, {'label': 'L.CE1H', 'value': 'L.CE1H'}, {'label': 'L.CE2H', 'value': 'L.CE2H'}, {'label': 'LUZECH', 'value': 'LUZECH'}, {'label': 'M.ALLH', 'value': 'M.ALLH'}, {'label': 'MARC5H', 'value': 'MARC5H'}, {'label': 'MAUZAH', 'value': 'MAUZAH'}, {'label': 'M.LARH', 'value': 'M.LARH'}, {'label': 'MTEZIH', 'value': 'MTEZIH'}, {'label': 'MTFERH', 'value': 'MTFERH'}, {'label': 'MTPEZH', 'value': 'MTPEZH'}, {'label': 'M.VIRH', 'value': 'M.VIRH'}, {'label': 'N.USSH', 'value': 'N.USSH'}, {'label': 'P.BORH', 'value': 'P.BORH'}, {'label': 'P.CHAH', 'value': 'P.CHAH'}, {'label': 'P.LIGH', 'value': 'P.LIGH'}, {'label': 'PRAT5H', 'value': 'PRAT5H'}, {'label': 'P.VEYH', 'value': 'P.VEYH'}, {'label': 'QUEUIH', 'value': 'QUEUIH'}, {'label': 'RANCEH', 'value': 'RANCEH'}, {'label': 'ROCHEH', 'value': 'ROCHEH'}, {'label': 'SAILLH', 'value': 'SAILLH'}, {'label': 'SALELH', 'value': 'SALELH'}, {'label': 'SARRAH', 'value': 'SARRAH'}, {'label': 'SSCANH', 'value': 'SSCANH'}, {'label': 'SSGENH', 'value': 'SSGENH'}, {'label': 'SSMC H', 'value': 'SSMC H'}, {'label': 'TEIL2H', 'value': 'TEIL2H'}, {'label': 'TEMPLH', 'value': 'TEMPLH'}, {'label': 'TREIGH', 'value': 'TREIGH'}, {'label': 'TUILIH', 'value': 'TUILIH'}, {'label': 'V.BENH', 'value': 'V.BENH'}, {'label': 'VENDEH', 'value': 'VENDEH'}, {'label': 'VERSIH', 'value': 'VERSIH'}, {'label': 'VLEREH', 'value': 'VLEREH'}, {'label': 'V.LOTH', 'value': 'V.LOTH'}]}}
```

If you know a way to make the web site charge faster and be able to charge, print all the dropdowns labels(values) please let my know.
--> Actually the dropdowns with my labels stops on the column DOC_PERF_HTB after this there is no labels/values insides the dropdowns.

Thanks for your help,
Arthur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick to charge all the dropdowns option was to add the following code in `dash_table.DataTable()` :

`css=[{"selector": ".Select-menu-outer", "rule": "display: block !important"}],`

My page still take a long time to charge but has all the labels inside my dropdowns !